# How to change ImageConstPtr data?

Tags: sensor-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

Please explain me how could I change raw data in **ImageConstPtr&** object?
I have a function like:

```
void filterImage (const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& rgb_msg)
{
  // something like rgb_msg->data[100] = 0;
}
```

So, I should change image data, and then pass **rgb_msg** to other functions.

I see deprecated functions *get_data_vec* and *set_data_vec* in **Image.h** file, but looks like I could not use them cause I have **const** modifier on object, and *set_data_vec* is non-const function.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28144/how-to-change-imageconstptr-data?/) by [Konstantin Cherenkov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1835/konstantin-cherenkov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to try something like below:

```
void filterImage (const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& rgb_msg)
{
    sensor_msgs::Image current_rgb_msg;
    current_rgb_msg = *rgb_msg;   
}
```

You can further manipulate the value from `current_rgb_msg` variable.

---

Originally posted by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) with karma: 1053 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-21**:
It's better to put the declaration of "current_rgb_msg" in class scope.

**Comment by [Konstantin Cherenkov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1835/konstantin-cherenkov/) on 2012-02-22**:
As I understood, "current_rgb_msg" is a copy of object, referenced by "rgb_msg". Ok, that means, that all changes would be actually for "current_rgb_msg" object. Could you please explain, how to convert "current_rgb_msg" to "const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr&" after all changes? Thanks.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-22**:
You cannot convert/overwrite the incoming "rgb_msg", because it is a constant value(it's read-only variable). I'm not so into openCV, I think, you can try what dlaz and Eddit suggested, that's by using straightaway cv_bridge for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should probably copy the data to another sensor_msgs::Image and then modify it, as you are supposed to read only from const data.

---

Originally posted by [TomTUM](https://answers.ros.org/users/547/tomtum/) with karma: 481 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4